# update json result in mysql sequentially

Tags: php, mysql, json

I actually want to update mysql with the output in same order. I am having a db where some data is already present and there sendondate is common. I tried to update but it only update the last output only not all the sequence. Please help me out from this..

```
<?php
    $data = '[{"message":"Hello+Test+Message","sender":"test","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-23 12:27:00","provider":"aaaa"},{"message":"Hello+Test+Message","sender":"test","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DELIVERD","sendondate":"2015-04-23 12:27:00","provider":"aaaa"}]';


       // $objs = json_decode($data);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Password*9","sms9");
        $objs = json_decode($data,true);
        foreach ($objs as $obj){
            $repor = $obj['messageStatus'];
           // echo $repor . '<br />';
            $sen= $obj['sendondate'];
            //echo $sen;

            $repor=array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($repor))
        {
            $sql2=  "Update detail SET Delivery='$repor' WHERE Datetime='$sen'";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql2)){
            echo "up";
            }
        }

        }   

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `$repor=array()` and the `while` condition (I can't see, what was it's purpose):

```
<?php

$data = '[
   {"message":"Hello+Test+Message","sender":"test","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-23 12:27:00","provider":"aaaa"},
   {"message":"Hello+Test+Message","sender":"test","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DELIVERD","sendondate":"2015-04-23 12:27:00","provider":"aaaa"}
]';

// $objs = json_decode($data);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Password*9","sms9");
$objs = json_decode($data,true);

foreach ($objs as $obj) {
    $repor = $obj['messageStatus'];
    // echo $repor . '<br />';
    $sen = $obj['sendondate'];
    //echo $sen;

    $sql2 = "Update detail SET Delivery='$repor' WHERE Datetime='$sen'";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql2)) {
       echo "up";
    }
}
```

**Update based on your comment:**

In sql if you want to modify specific rows, you have to match them using proper where conditions. Generally, it's not a good idea to select rows based on non-unique columns such as datetime. So, if you can alter both your db and json data, the usual way is to define some kind of id (usually integer number):

```
$data = '[
   {"id": 123, "message":"Hello+Test+Message","sender":"test","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DND","sendondate":"2015-04-23 12:27:00","provider":"aaaa"},
   {"id": 666, "message":"Hello+Test+Message","sender":"test","billcredit":"0.00","messageStatus":"DELIVERD","sendondate":"2015-04-23 12:27:00","provider":"aaaa"}
]';
...
    $id = $obj['id'];
    ...
    $sql2 = "Update detail SET Delivery='$repor' WHERE id=$id";
```

Or if you can't add extra columns, you must add one of already defined to distinguish between rows with the same datetime, for example the sender (the sender values must be different for the records to distinguish between them, which is not the case in you json sample data, but this is just the example of usage):

```
   ...
   $sender = $obj['sender'];
   ...
   $sql2 = "Update detail SET Delivery='$repor' WHERE Datetime='$sen' AND sender='$sender'";
```

**Extra security tip:**
Generally, you should properly [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the data before sending to the db, to prevent [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Alternatively you can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with [binded parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: i also try removing the same as you mention but it only take the last value of the stored in $repor. I am not being able to store all the value of $repor sequentially. @Honza Haering

Comment: In you json data, you have the same "sendondate" for both records. So the where clause selects the same record in the db. The db first updates the "Delivery" column to "DND" and then replaces it with "DELIVERD". Both on the same row in db with Datetime='2015-04-23 12:27:00'.

The question is, what do you want to have in db after those updates? Two records, one with 'DND' and one with 'DELIVERD'?

Comment: it will going to deduct credit.. I think i failed to make you understand. I have send sms to two number. So on same time the message will get inserted in db. Now i have two indentical sendondate in one table. After i receive the json once delivered then i need to update the status on both the number. Now problem is its get updated with same status to both not the respective status. So please help me.. @Honza Haering

Comment: OK, some basics: sql UPDATE updates all the rows that match the criteria, in your case the Datetime. If you want to update only one of these rows, you must have another column by which you can distinguish it. The most usual way is to have some id (int number), that is unique across the table. Then you reference this number in your json {"id": "123", ...} and use it in your where clause: WHERE id='$id'.
If you can't do it this way (can't add this extra column to db and to json data), then you have to find another column by which you match the records. The "sender" maybe.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope, that will point you the right direction. Let me know, if still unclear.